# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 68 and 10 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT]

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras, keras-layer

I am using a LSTM and a VNN to convert active text to passive text. I am feeding in tokenized data to the lstm and getting a feature vector of shape (68,1) and I am then using that as input data for a vanilla neural net along with an output probability matrix of shape (68,10,10). However, I am getting the following error when I try model.fit():

```
Epoch 1/100
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"/Users/pranavpallavalli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/LstmSeq2Seq/ActivePassiveLSTM.py", line 77, in <module>
vnn.fit(feature_vec,output_prob_matrix,32,100)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
 File "/var/folders/6q/v9z_sbmd25q2ntjw2pn6hfk80000gn/T/__autograph_generated_fileg6buiumj.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
    return self.compiled_loss(
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 139, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 243, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/Users/pranavpallavalli/miniforge3/envs/env_tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1327, in mean_squared_error
    return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 68 and 10 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_1/dense_1/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [68,10], [?,10,10].
```

My code for the model set up is:

```
lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(10,input_shape=(1,10)))
lstm.add(Dense(1))
feature_vec = lstm(lstm_input_sequences)
feature_vec = np.array(feature_vec)
# np.reshape(feature_vec,(68,10,10))
vnn = Sequential()
vnn.add(Input(1,68))
vnn.add(Dense(units=10,activation='sigmoid'))
loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
vnn.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(vnn.summary())
vnn.fit(feature_vec,output_prob_matrix,32,100)
```

Once again, the shape of feature_vec is (68,1) and the shape of output_prob_matrix is (68,10,10)

I am a beginner and I am not too sure about why Im getting this. Please do help me out!! Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the error. The problem is that the first LSTM is not returning a sequence out of the input you give it. I  used `return_sequences=True` to make it work. I also merged the two models in the training, here is why:

Calling `model.fit` between `feature_vec` and `lstm_input_sequences` while using `MeanSquarredError` as loss function is not correct. `MeanSquarredError` is only used to compare two vectors of same size and 'nature'. Here, you are trying to compare features (feature_vec) with a tokenized sentence (output_prob_matrix), while you are supposed to compare two tokenised sentences `lstm_input_sequences` and `output_prob_matrix`. This is why it is mandatory to merge the 'lstm' and 'vnn'.

the `model.fit` should not be called between `feature_ven` and `output_prob_matrix` since they have different shapes and you are using the `MeanSquarredError` as loss function. So the `model.fit` should be called between the `lstm_input_sequences` and `output_prob_matrix` which are supposed to have identical shapes.

This is my suggested code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
import numpy as np

lstm_input_sequences = np.zeros((68, 1, 10))
output_prob_matrix = np.zeros((68, 10, 10))

lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True,  input_shape=(1, 10)))
lstm.add(Dense(1))

lstm.add(Dense(units=10, activation='sigmoid'))
loss_fn = MeanSquaredError
lstm.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

lstm.summary()
lstm.fit(lstm_input_sequences, output_prob_matrix, 32, 100)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for sharing this! This makes a lot of sense, especially the aspect of combining the vnn and the lstm. But the one thing I do not seem to understand is why you reassigned lstm_input_sequences & output_prob_matrix to np.zeros((68, 10, 10)). Won't this erase all my data? Originally my lstm_input_sequences is of shape (68,1,10) and output_prob_matrix represents the position at which a word occurs in the sentence in passive form and is of shape (68,10,10). What can I do here? Can I just proceed without doing any reshaping?

Comment: Ok just a follow up on my previous question. It seems to work even though lstm_input_sequences and output_prob_matrix but the accuracy is horrible. Its literally 5% accuracy lol

Comment: For the first question, I assigned those variables to zeros just to check if the model architecture is working and because I don't have the data. In your case, you should assign the real data to those variables in order to train the network. lstm_input_sequences of shape (68,1,10) should also be working. For the accuracy, I can't say anything since I don't know the dataset and the hyperparameters used for training.